# VC++ の #import はどんなとき使う？

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Visual C++ には `#import` というディレクティブがあることを[別のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/50142/19110)で知りました。[MSDN によると](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=vs-2017) `#import` は「タイプ ライブラリからの情報を組み込むために使用」するらしいのですが、いまいちユースケースが分かりません。

`#import` は具体的にどのような場面で使うディレクティブなのでしょうか？

#### 関連質問？

- [C++ include and import difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/172262/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [Replacement for #import in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/650578/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++言語ではヘッダーファイルでプロトタイプ宣言を行い、リンクは別の仕組みを使っています。ヘッダーファイルはC++言語特有のもので、他のプログラミング言語との相互運用が困難になります。

そこでMicrosoftは言語非依存・プラットフォーム非依存の[COM; Component Object Model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/component-object-model--com--portal)を定義しました。この中でIDL; Interface Definition LanguageとTLB; Type Libraryが定義されています。
その上で、C++言語ソースからType Libraryを読み込む機能が`#import`ディレクティブとなっています。

ですので、COMを呼び出しを行わない限りは出番はありません。

Answer (score 1):

c++ で、odbc や、 ADO を使って、 データベースやExcel フォームへアクセスするという場合には、
使うこともあります。
データベースアクセスには、普通、DAOとかRDOとかなので、特にADO指定でないと、出番は少ないかもしれませんね。
Oracle はいまだにoo4oとかですものね。
あとは、excel が吐き出すダブルクォーテーションで、フィールドを括った書式のcsvファイルをc++のチカラ技でなく、
何とか外部ライブラリーを使って読み書きしたい場合は出番があるかもしれないですね。

ADOを使うには、以下のサイトが参考になります。

Visual C++ での ADO プログラミング
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/visual-c-ado-programming?view=sql-server-2017

ちなみに c/c++言語で #import を使わずに、 IDispach* を使ってADO 等の COM オブジェクトにアクセスする方法は
あるにはありますが。かなり大変なので、使えるのであれば #import ディレクティブを使うとよいでしょう。

gcc など、　#import がサポートされていないコンパイラ群で、ADO 経由で SQL-Server へアクセスするなんて、
考えただけでも嫌になるほど面倒臭いですから。

csvにADO経由でアクセスする方法は比較的簡単に実験できると思うので、
実際に使ってみるのもよいかもしれません。