# #includeプリプロセッサ指令を使用するプログラミング言語

Tags: プログラミング言語, compiler, preprocessor

CやC ++以外の言語ではプリプロセッサディレクティブとして#includeを使用していますか？

Comment: 過去の質問も同様ですが、**質問の対象を明確にしてください**。あなたの質問の仕方だと「使いもしない、興味もない」言語の情報が回答としてつく可能性があり、質問者・回答者双方にとって有益なやり取りとは思えません。

Comment: @CodyRutscher これは[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)かもしれないなと思いました。なぜそのようなプログラミング言語を知りたいのでしょうか？

Comment: 私はちょうど言語間にパターンがあるかどうかを調べようとしています

Comment: @CodyRutscher 単に `#include` という名前であれば良いのでしょうか？　それとも[前回のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/50142/19110)のように、`#include` 相当の機能を持つものをお探しなのでしょうか？

Comment: 等価関数 @nekketsuuu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どういう答えが期待されているのかわからないけど、オイラの常用している範囲での話をするなら（その他言語は知らん）

文字通り `#include` と書く言語は [c](/questions/tagged/c) [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) くらい。他言語だと

[m4](/questions/tagged/m4) が `include()` がほぼ同機能 `sinclude()` ってのもある
[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) だと `require` がほぼ同機能
[ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) だと `require` も `include` もあるが挙動が違う
[visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) だと csproj ファイルに `<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />` のような記述があるけど多分期待されているものとは違う。

十分にデバッグされているソースコードが既にあって、それを自プロジェクトにて使いたい、ような要望は必ずあるので、どの言語であっても類似の機構は何らかの形で **ある** でしょう。その機構を起動するキーワードが `include` であるかどうかは話が別ってことで。 `package` だったり `import` だったり `require` だったり。