# IPアドレスと電話番号

Tags: ssh, ftp

IPアドレスを使用してデスクトップまたはラップトップのファイルシステムにSSHまたはFTPで転送できるのと同じ方法で、電話番号を使用して電話機のファイルシステムにSSHまたはFTPで転送することは可能ですか。

Comment: なぜ一般的なメール等での簡単な方法を使わず、質問のような方法をしたいのかをもう少し具体的に書いてもらうと良いのではないでしょうか。 / 単なる技術的な興味があるだけなのか、何か必要に迫られてなのかが分かりません。

Comment: 少し検索してみた範囲だと、iOSに対してssh/ftpで接続するにはいわゆる"脱獄(Jailbreak)"が必要なようです。

Comment: タグを見落としていましたが、電話機というのはiPhoneに限定して想定しているのですか?

Comment: それはどんな電話でも構いません @PicoSushi

Comment: 特定企業の特定製品限定かもしれませんが、こんなのがあるようです。[CUCM で IP フォン、SCCP フォン、SIP フォンを登録するプロセス](https://community.cisco.com/t5/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9C%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3-%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88/cucm-%E3%81%A7-ip-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3-sccp-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3-sip-%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B9/ta-p/3133787)

Comment: CUCM、SCCP、およびSIPとは何ですか

Comment: 紹介リンク先に書いてありますが、CUCMはCisco社の製品名orサービス名です。SCCPとSIPはプロトコル名です。それぞれ詳細は検索してみてください。

Comment: [過去にもコメントしましたが](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/50478/include%e3%83%97%e3%83%aa%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%bb%e3%83%83%e3%82%b5%e6%8c%87%e4%bb%a4%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e7%94%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%83%97%e3%83%ad%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%9f%e3%83%b3%e3%82%b0%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e#comment52676_50478)、ある程度質問の対象を絞り込んでもらわないとあなた自身が「興味のない」ものについての回答が付く事になり、お互いにとって好ましくありません。 / 電話機(今回想定しているのはスマートフォン？)でもiOS、Android以外にも色々な種類があり、それぞれアプローチが違ってくるはずです。

Answer (score 2):

電話機のファイルシステムというのはよく分かりませんが、電話回線を利用したファイル通信は技術的には可能であり、過去に（現在も？）実際にダイヤルアップ通信というものが行われていました。

これはOSI参照モデルで言うところの第1層〜第2層に相当し、この上にIPやTCP/UDPが存在するため、SSHやFTP、SFTPなども利用可能です。

[ダイヤルアップ接続 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%80%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E6%8E%A5%E7%B6%9A)

[【ピーヒョロヒョロ】今どき、ダイヤルアップ接続でTwitterにポストしてみた | PreBell](https://prebell.so-net.ne.jp/news/pre_17050201.html)

Comment: あなたは私がそれをする方法を知っていますか？

Comment: 2つめの参考URLとして記載されている記事にて、HTTPSの通信を行っている様子が描かれているので、これを参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

電話回線とインターネットは、ネットワーク構成も運用形態も異なりますから、「同じ方法」というのは一般的には実現不可能です。

送信側でファイルをGoogleドライブにアップロードしておき、携帯電話の番号をつかってショートメッセージ(SMS)でアップロードした場所を知らせる。
受信側（携帯電話）では、SMSのメッセージを読み取ってGoogleドライブからファイルをダウンロードするアプリを稼働させておく（もしくは携帯電話の持ち主がSMSを読んで、ファイル転送アプリを操作する）。
というような仕掛けを作っておけばファイルの転送は可能だと思います。

Googleドライブとのやり取りには、FTPとSFTPのプロトコルが使えます。

Comment: 電話番号やIMEI番号のようなもので電話のファイルシステムにアクセスする何らかの方法がなければなりません。

Comment: 「同じ方法」というのは一般的には実現不可能と申し上げました。　携帯電話の持ち主なら、FTPクライアントで自分の携帯電話のファイルシステムにFTPしてきたファイルを保存する事ができます。スキルをお持ちなら同様の機能を持つアプリを開発することも可能でしょう。